# table Entry_table has no column named DATE (code 1) INSERT INTO Entry_table(AMOUNT,NAME,CARET,DATE,BALANCE,AMOUNT_PAID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am getting this error when i try to insert data can anyone tell me what's the problem ? table Entry_table has no column named DATE (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Entry_table(AMOUNT,NAME,CARET,DATE,BALANCE,AMOUNT_PAID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)

Here is my code:

```
        package com.example.bipinp.mithun;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
        import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
        import android.text.Editable;
        import android.text.TextWatcher;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.Spinner;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Calendar;
        import java.util.List;

        public  class DailyEntry extends AbstractActivity implements TextWatcher {
            private Button btnsbmtentry;
            private Spinner spiner2;
            private EditText milkcaret,amount,amountp,prevbal,currentBal,totalBal;
            private TextView mtxtDate;
            DatabaseHelper mydb;
            int amnt,amntp,sub,currB,prevB,totalB;
            String sAmnt,sAmntp,subvalue,sCurrBal,sPrevBal,stotalBal,strDate;
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int dd = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int mm = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int yy = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily_entry);
                mydb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

                mtxtDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
                btnsbmtentry=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsubmitentry);
                spiner2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
                milkcaret=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt1_de);
                amount=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt2_de);
                amountp=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt3_de);
                prevbal = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt4_de);

                totalBal = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt4_deTotBal);
                amount.addTextChangedListener(this);
                amountp.addTextChangedListener(this);
                prevbal.addTextChangedListener(this);
                mtxtDate.setText(dd+"/"+mm+"/"+yy);



                adddata2();
                loadspinner();
                spiner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        String pos = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                        String bale = mydb.balance(pos);
                        prevbal.setText(bale);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });

            }

            private void loadspinner() {
                DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
                List<String> labels = db.getAllLabels();
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,labels);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spiner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }

            private void adddata2() {
                btnsbmtentry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        boolean insertdata2 = mydb.insertdata2(spiner2.getSelectedItem().toString(),milkcaret.getText().toString(),amount.getText().toString(),amountp.getText().toString(),totalBal.getText().toString(),mtxtDate.getText().toString());
                        if (insertdata2)
                            Toast.makeText(DailyEntry.this, "Record Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(DailyEntry.this, "Databse Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }


            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                currentBal = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt4_deCurrB);


                sAmnt = amount.getText().toString();
                sAmntp = amountp.getText().toString();

                sPrevBal = prevbal.getText().toString();
                try {
                    amnt = Integer.parseInt(sAmnt);
                    amntp = Integer.parseInt(sAmntp);
                    sub = amnt-amntp;

                    prevB = Integer.parseInt(sPrevBal);

                }catch (NumberFormatException e){

                }

                subvalue = String.valueOf(sub);
                currentBal.setText(subvalue);
                Log.d("prevb", "afterTextChanged: "+prevB);
                Log.d("currb","afterText:"+currB);
                stotalBal = String.valueOf(sub + prevB);

                totalBal.setText(stotalBal);

            }
        }
```

DatabaseHelper.class

```
package com.example.bipinp.mithun;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Bipinp on 2/18/2016.
 */
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Sales.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME1 = "Insert_table";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME2 = "Entry_table";

    public static final String COL_ID = "ID";
    public static final String COL_NAME = "NAME";

    public static final String COL_CUST_NAME = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_CARET = "CARET";
    public static final String COL_AMOUNT = "AMOUNT";
    public static final String COL_AMOUNT_PAID = "AMOUNT_PAID";
    public static final String COL_BALANCE = "BALANCE";
    public static final String COL_DATE = "DATE";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME1 + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME2 + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,CARET INTEGER,AMOUNT INTEGER,AMOUNT_PAID INTEGER,BALANCE INTEGER,COL_DATE TEXT,FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES Insert_table(ID_NAME))");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME1);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME2);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public boolean deleteRow(String name)
    {   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME1, COL_NAME + "= '" + name + "';", null) > 0;
    }

    public boolean insertdata(String name){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_NAME,name);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME1,null,contentValues);
        if(result == -1)
            return  false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public boolean insertdata2(String name,String caret,String amount,String amount_paid,String balance,String date){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_CUST_NAME,name);
        contentValues.put(COL_CARET,caret);
        contentValues.put(COL_AMOUNT,amount);
        contentValues.put(COL_AMOUNT_PAID,amount_paid);
        contentValues.put(COL_BALANCE,balance);
        contentValues.put(COL_DATE,date);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME2,null,contentValues);
        if (result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public List<String> getAllLabels(){
        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

        String selectQuery = " SELECT " + COL_NAME + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME1;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do { labels.add(cursor.getString(0));
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return labels;
    }
    public String balance(String name)
    {
        String label = null;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = " SELECT " + COL_BALANCE + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME2  +  " WHERE " + " rowid " + "= '"+(" SELECT " + " last_insert_rowid() " + " * FROM " + TABLE_NAME2  +  " WHERE " + " name " + " = " +name)+ "';";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);

        if(cursor != null)
        {
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                label = cursor.getString(0);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }

       return label;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the table actually have such a column? Please share your DDL statement.

Comment: @Mureinik i have shared my Databasehelper class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your create table statement says:

```
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME2 + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,CARET INTEGER,AMOUNT INTEGER,AMOUNT_PAID INTEGER,BALANCE INTEGER, "+
               "COL_DATE TEXT,FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES Insert_table(ID_NAME))");
                ^^^^^^^^
```

Hence your column is named `COL_DATE`, not `DATE`. `COL_DATE` is a better column name than `DATE` btw, since `DATE` is a reserved word for the SQL "Date" type.